# Log python message into file

Tags: python

I am new to python so I don't have enough knowledge on logging. my question is below.

I want to log any python result message into a text file

Ex

I have a code

```
a = 5
B = 10
a+c
```

If I run the above code it gives output message as
"NameError: name 'c' is not defined"

Is there any way I can log the above message into text file so that I can understand why the code failed by opening the text file.

Please assist

Comment: Do you run this as a script, or do you want to log the output from an interactive shell?

Comment: Just use stderr redirection: `python3 <file>.py 2> error.txt`

Comment: Python has a standard logging module. You can read a python 'official' tutorial on logging here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html. There is also a python website with helpful tutorials with one on logging here: https://realpython.com/python-logging/. And the reason your code doesn't work is exactly what it says - there is nothing named `c` and so it can't add it to something else. Logging to a text file also won't give you any more info than you are already getting, btw

Comment: I running it as a script actually my real script is different all I want is if my script fails due to invalid input I want to log the failure message to file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of doing so:

```
import logging

fileLog = r'\myError.txt'
logging.basicConfig(filename=fileLog , level=logging.DEBUG)
try:
    a = 5
    B = 10
    s = a+c 
except:
    logging.exception('message')
    raise
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Logging module, it's a ready to use module. Steps:

- Import logging
- Define the basicConfig
- Use it where you need logging

Example:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s :: %(levelname)s :: %(message)s',
    filename='file.log',
    filemode='a',
    level=logging.INFO
)

a = 6
b = int(input("what is b? (a is 6) "))

if a+b == 10:
    logging.info("b was 4")
else:
    logging.info("b was not 4")
```

Example logs should be like this in file.log file:

```
2022-08-08 19:32:16,197 :: INFO :: b was not 4
2022-08-08 19:32:58,938 :: INFO :: b was 4
```

You can find more info and details here: [Link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)